# issue in making part of input box uneditable in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am making a terminal command prompt (the user can write on input-box and press enter and recieves the command from backend).

I am passing a default value from model to my template for my input-box. This default value is a response that is fetched from backend and every time it changes (like different usernames and it is in form of "name $>" ) but I want to lock it before $ so user cannot go back and write before that, that is what I have tried:

```
var textValue = this.model.get("name") + " $> ";
var textString = String(textValue); 
var textStringLength = textString.length;
$("#textInput").on("change keyup keypress keydown", function(evt) {     
    if($("#textInput").val().length < textStringLength) {
       $("#textInput").val(textValue); 
    } 
});
```

but I still can edit it! surprisingly it only works for backspace (which means I can not delete it by backspace) but if I use arrow keys or put the mouse cursor in between i still can edit! Any idea?

That is my inputbox: `<input type="text" id="textInput" name="" style="background: #222; autofocus>` 
Any idea? with span as another solution?

Comment: Why not just have a non-editable HTML element (e.g. a `<span>`) *in front* of the input box and update the contents of that element with your `name $>` string?

Comment: if I use span the whole input box will be uneditable. That is my inputbox: <input type="text" id="textInput" name="" style="background: #222; autofocus> Can you explain me more?

Comment: See my answer below on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Why not lay out your HTML like this:

```
<span id="prefix"></span><input type="text" id="textInput" />
```

Then you can modify your code like so:

```
var textString = this.model.get("name") + " $> ";
$('#prefix').text(textString);
```

Now you can edit the command after the `>`, but the prompt is not editable.

You can see a crude example here: http://jsfiddle.net/5Nnqa/

Comment: I guess you have forgotten to update the fiddle coz it's not working.

Comment: @sanki - If you wait two seconds then the `fred $>` prompt appears in front of the text box. I said it was a crude example :-)  Just a proof of concept really.

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding this:

```
$("#textInput").attr("disabled",true);
```

after:

```
$("#textInput").val(textValue);
```

Comment: I don't think that's even possible to disable only half the textbox via JQuery..


why don't you use two separate textboxes with some css that make them look like single text box.

Answer (score 0):

if You use **2** textboxes like below then I think Your problem will be solved. I have already applied this logic for solving my own similar type problem.

```
<input type="text" id="textInput1" size="1" name="" style="border-right:0px;" value="$" readonly="readonly">
<input type="text" id="textInput" name="">
```

You will have use some **css** for adjustment.